# Yii relation between createURL and urlManager

Tags: php, yii, yii-booster

I'm new to web development, and I've spent hours trying to understand Yii and how it handle's URLs.  I've read scores of tutorials and still don't understand it.

*I'm trying to set the URL for a button widget, for a menu widget, for a Controller Action, and for a basic HTML link.  It appears that Yii handles all of this routing differently, and I can't get it to work.*

Here is one example. **I need to get from a page in the `protected/views/site` folder to a module in `protected/modules`.**  **ALL** of the following commands give me the CException error `SiteController cannot find the requested view [...] .../yii/framework/web/CController.php(878)` file when issuing the following command ...

```
$this->render(Yii::app()->createURL('module/action'));
$this->render(Yii::app()->createURL('/module/action'));
$this->render(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteURL('module/action'));
$this->render(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteURL('/module/action'));
$this->render('module');
$this->render('/module');
$this->render('//module')
$this->render('module/action');
$this->render('/module/action');
```

I thought I was getting this error because `createURL()` gives me `/app/index.php/module/action`.  Instead, I want `http://mysite/app/index.php/module/action`.  Thanks to @Jonnny, I was able to get the full URL with `createAbsoluteURL()`.
The problem is that I am still getting the same error.  If I type `http://mysite/app/index.php/module/action`, I get the module I want, but if I try to render the page through Yii, I get the CException error.

The frustrating thing is that I can move between controllers quite easily in other areas of Yii.  For example, if I set parameters to a YiiBooster widget with something like ...

```
array('label' => 'Menu Option',
      'url' => array('/controller/action')
```

... I get routed to `http://mysite/app/index.php/controller/action` no matter what controller I started with.  The URL pattern for a controller/action is the same URL pattern for a module/action, so why can't Yii take me to the module/action?

**UPDATE:**
Until I can understand Yii better, I am using a solution found on http://www.highnd.com/articles/yii-framework/yii-url-links-and-redirection.  I can now access a module using the command:
    `$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteURL('module'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Render is used to display a certain view file. You do not need to add a createUrl() before it. Just pass the controller/action you want to render, if you are rendering from a controller often you can just pass the view file name. So

```
$this->render('view', array('model' => $model)); // here view would be the view file (view.php) that relates to the model instance.
```

The Yii booster widget you are using is asking for a specific url that you can pass as a route. In short, I think you're using render incorrectly. It is used for displaying a view file with a layout.

> createUrl() - Creates a relative URL for the specified action defined in this
>   controller.
>
> createAbsoluteUrl() - Creates an absolute URL for the specified action
>   defined in this controller.

You need createAbsoulteUrl() if you want a full URL.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why createURL leaves off the `http://mysite/` part of the URL.

Comment: When I follow your example, I get the error `SiteController cannot find the requested view` because I'm trying to navigate to a module and for reasons I really wish I could understand, I can only access the module when I type the complete URL manually.

Comment: updated my answer, hopefully this answers your question about leaving off the `http://mysite/`

Comment: Using `createAbsoluteUrl()`, I am still getting `SiteController cannot find the requested view "http://mysite/app/index.php/controller"`. But if I type the URL in manually it works just fine.